# How to render the fire and smoke as different passes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, render-passes

Is it possible to render the fire and smoke (the same simulation), in Cycles, separately, for example as different passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Just do it as you normally would. Select both the domain and the smoke emitter and change their **"pass index".**

(in the illustration, the sphere is your smoke domain. It also shows how to get it on another pass in the compositor.)
[image]

---

Or you can change their layer, and render them on a different render layer.

Comment: Thank you very much!
In the first case I have to assign to the  domain and the emitter different  pass indexes? Will I able in this case to work separately, with  fire and smoke? Even though this is the same simulation (fire and smoke have the same emitter)?

Comment: How to render the fire and smoke as different render layers? In fact I need to be able to affect the fire without affecting the smoke, for example, to increase the brightness of fire without affecting the smoke. Therefore, I would like to render a fire and smoke in the different layers (passes) of an EXR file, or render the final image and the masks for the fire and smoke as separate layers-passes.

Comment: Well, to the first part, no, they should have the same index. If you want the fire and smoke on different "layers", you put them on different passes. I believe that it goes by the domain, so you should only have to change the pass of the domain. However, if you have the smoke and fire both being input to the same domain object, there is no way I know of to render them on different layers. You must create two different domain objects, and change one of them to pass index one.

Comment: (the fire can be left at 0, because everything starts at 0, and the smoke is now at 1, but if you want it to be seperate from other stuff in scene, you need it to be 2.)

Comment: About your second comment, if you are simply rendering them out to images, you can input the image sequence to the compositor and then not bother with much of that. If you want the fire to affect the smoke (for example, light it up so that where the fire is, the light is shed on the smoke, and not simply ignored), you are better off not using the render layers method, but object indexes, as render layers interacting is impractical, and you must duplicate objects just to cast lights and shadows to get interactions without seeing the objects.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you are using "fire and smoke" setting in one smoke domain, it will be more difficult to do this. You should create two domains, and use one as smoke, and another as fire. (and in the material for the "fire", remove all the smoke parts, because fire automatically comes with smoke in the smoke sim [who knew right, I thought that's what fire+smoke was for :P])

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed reply, I accept it, and try these methods. Can I ask you a question here in the comments, if it occurs later in the process?

Comment: Oh, and I noticed a difference in terminology, when I write "passes" I don't mean "samples" of the render, but the layers in the file after rendering, such as layers in the EXR file.

Comment: Sure, you can ask another question here in comments, but if you want, you can create a new question. If it is very similar to this question, you should post it here, but if it is an entirely different question, you should create a new question, then comment here asking me to answer (if you want) (also give the link please). (So you can bookmark this page if you want, so you can get to it later [that's what I do])

Answer (score 1):

Save them both(Fire and Smoke) as image render. In the node editor just disconnect the nodes that create smoke so thus the ones that created emission or fire alternately... What I mean is if you want to render smoke first then disconnect emission from the mix shader, then if you want fire just disconnect the density attributes and rgb that will create smoke... If there is another way for this let me know like separating them by layers...