# An individual model in an animation, which isn't effected by compositing and lighting of the animation

Tags: compositing-nodes, light

I'm trying to create an animation, everything is set up in the animation, including the composition. However since creating it, I wanted to add a logo at the end. I've created the logo and put it into the scene. However when it's on it's own and has it's own personal lighting it looks much better. In the scene the lighting which is needed for the rest of the animation to look good ruins it. Is it possible to fix this?

The compositor nodes, the logo in the scene and the logo before it goes into the scene is as follows:

[image: CompositorNodeSetup]
[image: LogoWithStars]
[image: LogoStanAlone]

As you can see the quality of the initial image (even though all settings are the same) is bad when it's placed into the new environment. It no longer looks metallic or shiny.

Ideally i'd like the stars (which are caused by another scene and added in the compositing section) to not shine through the Logo either. So it essentially blocks out the light from behind it.

The light at the moment is coming from two sources, One placed just above and behind the camera at an angle, and one just behind and below the text.

Just for context in case it's needed: The logo spins in from the background to the foreground landing just behind the text which is placed right up against the "lens".

Thank you for any help :)

Edit: Thank you cegaton, the link you posted solved my problem with the stars and already it looks MILES better. Thank you so much for that.

Still struggling to make the D Logo look Darker and more metallic. Going to have a mess around with angles and moving the lights to see what I can come up with. Thank you though cegaton. Big Help!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/why-are-my-objects-all-semi-transparent-in-the-compositor/49065#49065

Comment: can you add an image of your compositing nodes?

Comment: Don't **add** the stars layer. Use Alpha over.

Comment: Yeh i've altered a bunch in the compositor. Didn't realise just how in depth that thing is. Foreground and background etc. I've changed the order so that the Green background is background of the stars. Then that is the background of the main scene. Looks miles better now, thank you. Sill struggling with trying to get individual lighting for the logo shape itself. Even without that though, your guide makes it look great.

Comment: Please **ask that as a separate question on a new post**. Don't forget to add images that show the settings for your scene and lighting.

Comment: I think something like this may be what you are looking for. It is just a way to create a mask for a certain object, and then you can apply effects to just that object, or to all others except that object. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47157/20428